# Chrome extension - Inject script into a nested iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to inject a JS script into an iframe.

The aim is to inject the script using frame id

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tabId,
    {
        frameId: frameId,
        file: script.js
    },
    function(ret)
    {
        // Check ret
    }
);
```

However in my specific case, the iframe is located into another iframe so when I retrieve the frame list I can't find the targetted one.

```
chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames(
    {tabId:sender.tab.id},
    function(frames)
    {
        frames.forEach(
            function(frame)
            {
                console.log("### FRAME ID : " + frame.frameId);
                console.log("### FRAME URL : " + frame.url);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Output:

```
### FRAME ID : 0
### FRAME URL : https://domain0.com/path1
### FRAME ID : 159
### FRAME URL : https://domain0.com/path2
### FRAME ID : 160
### FRAME URL : https://domain1.com/path3
### FRAME ID : 162
### FRAME URL : about:blank
```

The targetted iframe is locatted inside the iframe 159.

Is there a way to inject a JS script into this nested iframe ?

Comment: The targetted iframe is located inside the iframe 159 `<iframe src="..."><!--iframe 159--><iframe src="..."><!--targetted iframe--></iframe></iframe>`

Comment: What is the URL of the target iframe?

Comment: It does not work with cross-domain iframes: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=826433 . Maybe you can use as workaround the content_script mechanism ?